# cakephp configure::read() error

Tags: cakephp, configure

I am new to `Cakephp`,

I need to use a variable in all Models and Controllers.

In `bootstrap.php`,

```
Configure::write('TimeField', 'time');
```

In `AppController.php`

```
public $TimeField = Configure::read('TimeField');
```

The above line gives error:

> Error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';'
>   File: D:\xampp\htdocs\inventory\app\Controller\AppController.php
>   Line: 37

Please advice. And please let me know if any other method I should follow because I also need this variable within all Models.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP function call in class property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665097/php-function-call-in-class-property)

Answer (score 0):

You may not use function calls in class property declarations.

You should declare

```
public $timeField;
```

and then initialize it in your __construct() method using

```
$timeField = Configure::read('TimeField');
```